# Transparent object with shadow

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is there anyway to add shadow to transparent objects in FabricJS? I've used set fill transparent and after that setshadow. But normally setshadow can't be seen because object is transparent.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using a [clip path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip) when drawing the object with the shadow. To do this with FabricJS you can subclass the object type you're generating the shadow from, and override the `_render` function to set a clip path that includes the area where the shadow falls but excludes the object itself. Ideally this reuses the code that actually draws the object.

```js
fabric.BoxShadow = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

  shadowColor: undefined,

  shadowBlur: 0,
  shadowOffsetX: 0,
  shadowOffsetY: 0,

  initialize(options) {
    this.callSuper('initialize', options);

    // Note: the way I have implemented this, the shadow settings cannot be changed after the object has been created.
    this._shadow = new fabric.Shadow({
      color: this.shadowColor,
      blur: this.shadowBlur,
      offsetX: this.shadowOffsetX,
      offsetY: this.shadowOffsetY
    });
  },

  _render: function(ctx) {
    ctx.save();

    // set clip path
    let [offsetX, offsetY, blur] = [this.shadowOffsetX,
      this.shadowOffsetY,
      this.shadowBlur
    ];

    let [top, left] = [this.width / -2, this.height / -2];

    let region = new Path2D();
    // The outer rectangle for our clipping path completely encompases the object and its shadow
    let bounds = {
      t: Math.min(top, top + offsetY - blur),
      l: Math.min(left, left + offsetX - blur),
      b: Math.max(top + this.height, top + this.height + offsetY + blur),
      r: Math.max(left + this.width, left + this.width + offsetX + blur),
    };

    region.rect(bounds.l, bounds.t, bounds.r - bounds.l, bounds.b - bounds.t);

    // now we subtract the actual object from our clipping path
    // Note: we have to add  beginPath function because the base class render code is going to treat this likc a CanvasRenderingContext2D instead of a Path2D
    region.beginPath = function() { };
    this.callSuper('_render', region);
    
    ctx.clip(region, "evenodd");

    // Fabric draws shadows, oddly enough, around the entire area rendered within this function. I haven't figured out the correct function to override to get our clip path to work with the normal fabric rendering pipeline
    this.shadow = this._shadow;
    // leverage the FabricJS shadow sizing logic
    this._setShadow(ctx);
    
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    this.shadow = undefined;

    ctx.restore();
  },
  
  _renderPaintInOrder: function(ctx) {
    if (ctx instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
     this.callSuper('_renderPaintInOrder', ctx);
    }
  }
});

(function() {
  let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

  canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
    top: 40,
    left: 40,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'lightblue'
  }));

  canvas.add(
    new fabric.BoxShadow({
      rx: 10,
      top: 10,
      left: 10,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      shadowColor: 'black',
      shadowBlur: 4,
      shadowOffsetX: 3,
      shadowOffsetY: 3
    })
  );

  canvas.setWidth(document.body.clientWidth);
  canvas.setHeight(document.body.clientHeight);
})();
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the FabricJS API has a shadow-without-shape option.

But you can easily create the shadow-only using a native html5 canvas and then use that native canvas as an image source for a Fabric.Image object.

With native html5 canvas you can create a shadow without it's source shape like this:

- Draw the shadowed shape,
- Use compositing to "erase" the shape -- leaving just it's shadow

[image]

Example code drawing shadow-only on a native html5 canvas:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var shadowBlur=8;
var x=shadowBlur;
var y=shadowBlur;
var width=100;
var height=65;
canvas.width=width+shadowBlur*2;
canvas.height=height+shadowBlur*2;

// draw the shadowed shape
ctx.shadowColor='black';
ctx.shadowBlur=8;
ctx.fillRect(x-ctx.shadowOffsetX,y,width,height);
// always clean up! -- undo shadowing
ctx.shadowColor='rgba(0,0,0,0';

// use compositing to remove the shape
// (leaving just the shadow);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';
ctx.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
// always clean up! -- set compositing to default
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Example creating a Fabric.Image using native html5 canvas as an image source:

```
// where "canvas" is a reference to an html5 canvas element
var myFabricImage=new fabric.Image(canvas, { left:0, top:0 });
```